# Fred Dews and his Bored Views

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, story

```
Fred Dews is (again) driving
his old clunker to the repair
shop in his rural hometown, when
he suddenly gets a phone call from
a childhood friend. Lord Kies,
as he is nowadays called, has
to be in the parliament the same
day, and needs a ride there,
since the train workers are on
strike, and the question of
line 30 legislation is going
to be handled that very afternoon.

Lord Kies is an important figure
in the leftist movement, and
since road trips with old friends
are always fun, they agree to meet
at Gordy's Fiesta restaurant for 
lunch, and start the trip from there.

Fred Dews realises, that his car
isn't only making funny noises,
but it's also very dirty, so he
turns into the automatic car wash,
which unfortunately malfunctions,
only leaving his 1979 Escort waxier
than before. Tom Rin, the car wash
owner, offers an inside-and-out
cleanup as an apology, but it has
to be interrupted since it took
too long: if the trip to the
capital begins a couple 
of hours late, it will be
completely meaningless to go at all.

"Gifford Fuddies", their favourite band,
blazing away on the 8-track car stereo,
Fred Dews then picks up his friend
(no time for lunch anymore, unfortunately),
and off into the distance they go.
```

Soon after, an unfortunate, but not totally unexpected mishap stops their journey.

What happens?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Their ...

> **Ford dies**.

They really should have seen this coming:

> All names in the story are pairs of words of the same length. You can get the second word by shifting each letter of the first word to the left on a keyboard. For example, **Lord Kies** has the transformations **L**→**K**, **O**→**I**, **R**→ **E** and **D**→**S**.
>
>  This rule applies not only to names, but to all words with a capital letter and the following one, for example "Escort waxier" and "Bored Views". Parliament will discuss line 30 legislation and line 30 of the story is: capital [letter] begins a couple. And the "leftist movement" hints at the type of letter transformation.
>
>  Funny how many Fords fit the bill.

Comment: Nicely done! The party affiliation, by the way, also strictly implies direction.

Comment: Oh, I didn't really notice that; that's even better. This fun puzzle has made me very happy.